# Am using the bool tool addon causes the cutter to be deleted

Tags: modeling, interface

I haven't changed any settings it just started to happen. I checked both the the display wireframe and fast transformations in the bool tool addon and that doesn't seem to have any effect. As you can see from the pictures I am just using normal cubes.

Comment: I think you forgot to post the pictures.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I6XA.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV7bp.png

Comment: nvm. I was using cntrl+shift+- when I should have been using cntrl+-